# I get an error when training simple Neural Network in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network

I have build simple neural network in MATLAB as shown in below code, and input and output data are of dimensions `128x1`, I divided the input data as `21x1` for validation and 107 for training:

```
clear all; clc; clear;  

bits = randi([0 1], 1 , 128);                 %Original generated data 
data_temp = bi2de(reshape(bits,128/2,2));   
data_mod = (1/sqrt(2))*qammod(data_temp , 4);  

inputs = [real(data_mod); imag(data_mod)];      %the input data of input layer (128 x 1); 
outputs = bits.';                               %output data from output layer (128 x 1); 

inputs_len = 128;                    %length of input data 
outputs_len = 128;                   %length of output data 

IN_V1 = inputs(end-20:end);                     %Test validation input vector
OUT_V1 = outputs(end-20:end);                   %Test Validation output Vector 

Train_seq_in = inputs(22 : end);               %Training inpur Data
Train_seq_out = outputs(22:end);               %Training output Data 

%build Neural network
options1 = trainingOptions('adam','MaxEpochs',2000,'InitialLearnRate',0.001,'MiniBatchSize',10,'Shuffle','every','L2Regularization',0,'Plots','training-progress','ValidationData',{IN_V1,OUT_V1})
layers =[sequenceInputLayer(107) fullyConnectedLayer(1024) reluLayer() fullyConnectedLayer(outputs_len) regressionLayer];

%train network 
 Net1 = trainNetwork(Train_seq_in,Train_seq_out,layers,options1);                  %Training the Network real
```

When I run the above code, I get an error of :

```
Error using trainNetwork (line 165)
The validation sequences are of feature dimension 21 but the input layer expects sequences of feature
dimension 107.

Error in quetion (line 24)
 Net1 = trainNetwork(Train_seq_in,Train_seq_out,layers,options1);                  %Training the Network
 real
```

However I think that's not logical because validation data should be smaller than testing data!!

I tried to change the Validation data be be same of input data as below :

```
%build Neural network
options1 = trainingOptions('adam','MaxEpochs',2000,'InitialLearnRate',0.001,'MiniBatchSize',10,'Shuffle','every','L2Regularization',0,'Plots','training-progress','ValidationData',{IN_V1,OUT_V1})
layers =[sequenceInputLayer(21) fullyConnectedLayer(1024) reluLayer() fullyConnectedLayer(outputs_len) regressionLayer];

%train network 
 Net1 = trainNetwork(IN_V1,IN_V1,layers,options1);                  %Training the Network real
```

but in that case I get another strange error as below :

```
Error using trainNetwork (line 165)
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

Error in quetion (line 24)
 Net1 = trainNetwork(IN_V1,IN_V1,layers,options1);                  %Training the Network real

Caused by:
    Error using reshape
    To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

Please anyone can help me in solving that issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second error: 
Error using trainNetwork (line 165)
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

```
Error in quetion (line 24)
 Net1 = trainNetwork(IN_V1,IN_V1,layers,options1);                  %Training the Network real

Caused by:
    Error using reshape
    To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

When you modify the size of input layer, you should also modify the size of output layer so you should replace this line:

```
layers =[sequenceInputLayer(21) fullyConnectedLayer(1024) reluLayer() fullyConnectedLayer(outputs_len) regressionLayer];
```

by this line:

```
layers =[sequenceInputLayer(21) fullyConnectedLayer(1024) reluLayer() fullyConnectedLayer(21) regressionLayer];
```